# Access ARGV in arm assembly language

Tags: arm, gnu-assembler

I'm doing what should be a fairly simple exercise to print the number of arguments passed to a program, and then print the first argument as a string. I get the number of the arguments, but the printing seems to just give random memory locations. I run the program like this:

`argdisplay ab ac ad`

which correctly prints the number of arguments, but not the argument string.

```
Argc: 4
Argc: �
```

My program is:

```
.data
stringD:     .asciz "Argc: %d\n"
stringS:     .asciz "Argc: %s\n"    

.text
.global main

main:
no_args:    
    push {ip, lr}
    mov r1, r0
    ldr r0, =stringD
    bl printf
arg_string: 
    ldr r1, [sp, #8]
    ldr r0, =stringS
    bl printf
    pop {ip, pc}

.global printf
.end
```

My understanding of the argv is that it is an array separated by four bytes, so I put in #8 to try and print the second argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `argv` argument isn't passed on the stack.  It's the second argument to your `main` function, so it is in `r1` on entry to main.  So:

- You need to save it (or a pointer to the desired string) before overwriting `r1` for the call to `printf`
- You need to save this in a call-preserved register (`r4-r8, r10`) (or on the stack, but that is less convenient)
- You need to save and restore that register at the beginning and end of your function

Here is a fixed version.  Since `argv` from `r1` is a pointer to the zeroth pointer in the `argv` array, then 4 bytes later will be the pointer to the first argument `argv[1]`, the one you want to print.  We save this in `r4` around the first call to `print`, and add `r4` to the list of registers to be pushed and popped.

```
main:
    push {r4, ip, lr}
    ldr r4, [r1, #4]

    mov r1, r0
    ldr r0, =stringD
    bl printf

    mov r1, r4
    ldr r0, =stringS
    bl printf

    mov r0, #0      // return 0
    pop {r4, ip, pc}
```

A couple other notes:

- We zero out `r0` on exit so that our `main` function returns 0 indicating success.  Returning a random value is annoying to users who want to test the exit code.
- You probably don't want to label both outputs as `Argc`.
- `.global printf` at the end should probably be `.extern printf`.  You aren't defining `printf` in this module, you are telling the assembler that it will be found in another module.  Also it would make more sense to put this directive *before* the calls to `printf` (maybe at the top of the file).
- The labels `no_args` and `arg_string` aren't used as branch targets anywhere, so they have no effect and might as well be comments (in which case they could be more descriptive).
- `.end` is unnecessary, unless you are going to put additional stuff after it that you want the assembler to ignore.  It's more likely to be an annoyance, if you add more actual code at the end of the file and then wonder why the assembler isn't assembling it.
- Since you don't intend to write to `stringD` or `stringS`, put them in the read-only data section.  Replace `.data` with `.section .rodata`.
- It would be nice to handle gracefully the case when no arguments are passed.  Currently it sort of works, since if no arguments are present then `argv[1]` is null, and `printf` on Linux accepts a null pointer with `%s` and prints the string `(null)`.  But you could think about nicer options.

Comment: Excellent! Thanks it works. The no_args, and arg_string were there so I could set a breakpoint in gdb. I didn't know about .extern that is useful. Thanks again.